# When trying to log in my website i keep getting a: 2 errors prohibited this user from being saved: Email cant be blank, email cant be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create users for my website and when signing up for the website I want the users information to go in the my backoffice. I installed gem Devise and gem CanCanCan, but when i try to sign up in the sign up page it keeps saying  2 errors prohibited this user from being saved: Email cant be blank, email cant be blank. I checked similar questions but haven't been able to correct my problem.

I'm on ruby on rails obv

Here's my migration:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable          
      t.string :email                
      t.string :encrypted_password   
      t.string :token               

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Here's my user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_secure_password

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

Here's my users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role)
      end
end
```

registrations
new.html.erb:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Tell my if im missing anything but i dont think so I'm new to rails so i might be
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a custom signup view or you're using the devise one?

Comment: Of course! I'm using devise, i putted the registrations new.html.erb in the question

Comment: What is `resource_name`?

Comment: i actually don't know what resource_name represents or what it should be to be honest, I'm trying to understand better devise right now

Answer (score 0):

`has_secure_password` is for custom authentication and is not necessary/should not be used with Devise.

Delete your `UsersController` and your `email` validation in the `User` model. Devise handles all of this for you.

If you want to whitelist additional attributes on signup that Devise does not account for (in your case it is only `role`), then add the following to your `ApplicationController`...

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:role])
  end
```

With well maintained and battle tested gems like Devise, it is really important to read the documentation and not stray from it unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: i changed the <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %> in new.html.erb to <%= form_for User, :url => {:action => "savenew"} do |f| %>  and im now stuck with an undefined method to_key

Comment: #<for Class:0x00007f702611ea98

Comment: Not sure why you would do that...as I said, stick to the default unless you have a reason not to do so.

Comment: So i guess I'm on the right path but here's the problem that followed, when i signed in it said that i wasnt authorized to access this page, which his probable the dashboard of the backoffice and it would be normal since i probable was a regular user and only admin have access to dashboard but now i cant go back to the sign in page

Comment: but i think i should be able to resolve my problems alone so thanks for the help!